# Sharepoint Portal using existing sql server database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

There is a web application which is built in asp.net webforms with entity framework. Database sqlserver 2008 R2.
I need to build a new sharepoint portal which will be using the exisiting database i.e., using its table , views , storedprocedure, user defined table type etc. 
Can we include entity framework in sharepoint ?

One way i am able to use the external database by using external content type. but it seems it is not serving the purpose.
Any suggestion is appreciable !

Answer (score 1):

I usually separate between custom databases and SharePoint data.

If I have a custom database I don't try to display that in built-in SharePoint views such as list-views etc. I build custom UI - webparts, application pages etc which displays custom database data in ASP.NET or javascript controls. I may also build custom code to display combined data from both SharePoint and a custom database - I get the custom database data e.g. via Entity Framework and the SharePoint data via REST API/CAML queries or some other way and then combine the data in custom code.

Operations in SharePoint data may trigger changes in custom database database - e.g. via Event listeners. User actions in the custom UI may invoke updates in both SharePoint data and custom database data.

Alot of coding ahead with this approach, but I haven't seen any good quick solution except for simple scenarios where External Content Type suffices.

Comment: Thanks for response. So can we use entity framework with custom code like visual webpart in sharepoint solution via REST API ? can you provide any link if possible ?

Comment: I am looking for this possibility as because the from that SP portal i have to fetch and update the data of the external database.